# how to evaluate homotopy group of this specific structure

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology, homotopy-theory

I am a Ph.D. student of physics and now I have some problems regarding the evaluation of homotopy group of a specific structure.

In a paper, a specific topological structure is defined. The structure is a map from a circle to $GL(m,\mathbb{C})$.

The paper claims the first homotopy classes can be indexed by an integer which is given by:

$$\nu_1=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\text{Tr}[U(k)^{-1}i\partial_kU(k)]$$

where $U$ is the map which maps $k\in[-\pi,\pi]$ to invertible $m\times m$ complex matrices. $k=-\pi$ and $k=\pi$ are identified to form a circle.

I have some background in undergraduate topology and I know what a homotopy group is. However, in undergraduate class there's no metric hence no differential operator in topological spaces so I don't know where this formula comes from.

Can someone give me a reference or explanation of this formula?

Comment: You want $U$ to map into $GL(m, \mathbb{C})$, not all $m\times m$ complex matrices. The reasons being: 1. $U(k)^{-1}$ only exists if $U(k) \in GL(n, \mathbb{C})$, and 2. the set of $m\times m$ complex matrices is contractible so the first homotopy group is trivial, whereas $GL(n, \mathbb{C})$ has first homotopy group $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will edit it accordingly. But where does the formula comes from?

Comment: The integrand is the chern form. The integral is called the chern number. The chern class is usually thought to live in cohomology, but under the right circumstances it can be associated  to homotopy group as well.

Comment: any recommended books？@ziggurism